# Alternative to Node for Merging External Properties of topojson

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have already looked here, here, and here:

[D3.js: How to combine 2 datasets in order to create a map and show values on.mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320835/d3-js-how-to-combine-2-datasets-in-order-to-create-a-map-and-show-values-on-mou)

[How to add properties to topojson file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444261/how-to-add-properties-to-topojson-file?lq=1)

https://github.com/topojson/topojson-1.x-api-reference/blob/master/Command-Line-Reference.md

They were a great help in getting me as close as I am now. **However, I'm attempting to recursively parse several datasets in .tsv format and join them together with the json geometry data.** I use the word join loosely; I know that topojson has some command line abilities to join .tsv to the json file. I think that would simplify things a lot, but if I'm not mistaken that requires Node. I tried many times to get Node working on my computer, it is either a compatibility issue or I'm not adept enough.

So, simply put, my question is:

**Bearing in mind that I don't have Node, what changes do I need to make (data file related, or other) to get my block working (parsing dynamically)**

I'm assuming that it's not working because of my chaotic data structure (as suggested by the post title), but if you think its something else, let me know.

My block:

http://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/42f4534b2168a00694219888ebb1a2fb

Comment: And what is your question actually?

Comment: Let me bold face that for clarity. Ok I bold faced much of the important details, the post title puts it most terse though.

Comment: There is also a visual way to see my problem, if you go to my block and scroll the range back and forth, you will notice the data is only rendered once. The colors and data all stay the same. This is a visual way to see how my block is not parsing dynamically. Perhaps because of an overly complicated merging of data sets.

Comment: I trimmed the post down and put it as succinctly as I could. However, I do encourage viewing the block, it's definitely easier to see it than put it in words.